# NSTableView and implicit animation

Tags: macos, cocoa

When I use:
 ***NSTableView reloadDataForRowIndexes:***
 
I can see the animation when the row is refresh.
How I can disable this animation?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My mistake, I call reloadDataForRowIndexes: in the background thread.
The problem is disappeared, when I perform it in the main thread.